# creating turtles with functions

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am feeling very lazy and was wondering if I can create turtles using functions
ex:

```
def turtle(x_pos, y_pos, name):
    name = turtle.Turtle()
    name.goto(x_pos,y_pos)
```

is this possible or do I just need to suck it up and do it the long way?

Comment: Why don't you try and see? it would have been be much easier than creating SO account to post it here...

Comment: It's us possible, but you should _return_ the turtle instance. If you just create it, you can't do anything with is except in the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

No, this won't work for a couple of reasons:

```
def turtle(x_pos, y_pos, name):
    name = turtle.Turtle()
    name.goto(x_pos,y_pos)
```

First, calling `turtle.Turtle()` implies you did `import turtle` which will be undone by you defining a function named `turtle`.  That is, Python will look for `Turtle()` as a property of your function `turtle()`, not the **turtle** library.

Second, passing in, and setting a `name` value like `'yertle'` isn't going to give you a global variable `yertle` that contains a turtle.  That's not the way Python works.  What we can do instead is something like:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def create_turtle(x_pos, y_pos):
    turtle = Turtle()
    turtle.goto(x_pos, y_pos)

    return turtle

yertle = create_turtle(100, 200)
```

There is likely an introspection approach to pass in a string and set a global variable of that name, but that's way beyond learing to use turtle.